# Separating characters into new column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset, and require the times and not dates placed into a separate column relative to the date. Which can be indicated by `id`, to join the time with date.

dataset:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   origintime             id
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2021-03-04 18:44:25     1
 2 2021-03-04 18:28:32     2
 3 2021-03-04 18:25:55     3
 4 2021-03-04 18:23:00     4
 5 2021-03-04 18:20:00     5
 6 2021-03-04 18:15:58     6
 7 2021-03-04 18:11:41     7
 8 2021-03-04 18:10:57     8
 9 2021-03-04 18:10:33     9
10 2021-03-04 18:07:01    10
```

outcome:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   origintime   time      id
   <dttm>              <int>
 1 2021-03-04 18:44:25     1
 2 2021-03-04 18:28:32     2
 3 2021-03-04 18:25:55     3
 4 2021-03-04 18:23:00     4
 5 2021-03-04 18:20:00     5
 6 2021-03-04 18:15:58     6
 7 2021-03-04 18:11:41     7
 8 2021-03-04 18:10:57     8
 9 2021-03-04 18:10:33     9
10 2021-03-04 18:07:01    10
```

reproducible code:

```
structure(list(origintime = structure(c(1614883465.299, 1614882512.721, 
1614882355.215, 1614882180.074, 1614882000.671, 1614881758.214, 
1614881501.122, 1614881457.527, 1614881433.217, 1614881221.603
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = 1:10), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `format` with `%T` to extract the time component from the 'origintime' column while converting the 'origintime' to `Date` class

```
library(dplyr)  
df1 <-  df1 %>% 
         mutate(time = format(origintime, '%T'), origintime = as.Date(origintime))
```

---

Or use `separate` and return as `character` columns

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    separate(origintime, into = c('origintime', 'time'), sep=" ")
```

Comment: That does work! though, I was expecting to remove the time component from the original column, in your case, it remains in the same column whilst producing a new column `time`.

Comment: @no_'t'-lime i updated the post

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[ , c('origintime', 'time') := tstrsplit(origintime, " ")]
df
#    origintime id     time
# 1: 2021-03-04  1 18:44:25
# 2: 2021-03-04  2 18:28:32
# 3: 2021-03-04  3 18:25:55
# 4: 2021-03-04  4 18:23:00
# 5: 2021-03-04  5 18:20:00
# 6: 2021-03-04  6 18:15:58
# 7: 2021-03-04  7 18:11:41
# 8: 2021-03-04  8 18:10:57
# 9: 2021-03-04  9 18:10:33
#10: 2021-03-04 10 18:07:01
```